# missing reference parameters in lambda

Tags: c++, lambda, stl

I'm getting a data for a file as a queue of byte chunks (vector).
and need to start a thread for a dumping this data into the file.
without threading code works fine (if put lambda body to a function itself). but with a lambda thread function it doesn't work.

first of all - path inside a lambda is an empty, 
while(!one_file.empty()) postpone a loop body even the size of queue is not a zero.

what can be wrong with a parameters passing and capturing?

```
std::thread dump_to_file(std::string path,  std::queue<std::vector<char>>&& one_file) {
    return std::thread {[&]() {
            std::ofstream out((path + ".bak").c_str());
            while (!one_file.empty()) {
                std::copy(one_file.front().begin(), one_file.front().end(), std::ostream_iterator<char>(out));
                one_file.pop();
           }
   }};
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are capturing a reference to a function local variable.  `path` goes out of scope when you return from the function so now your lambda is referring to a destroyed object.  If you instead capture by value(`[=]`) then the variables will live on in the lambda object.

You could also pass both variables to the function via reference and then you could capture them by reference as they would still exist from the call site of `dump_to_file`

Comment: capure by value a huge queue is not effective?

Comment: @amigo421 I have not tried it but you might be able to move the queue into the lambda with `[one_file{std::move(one_file)}]`

Comment: I mean - probably in this case, more effective way is a passing both as parameters instead of variables capturing?

Comment: @amigo421 I just added another way you could do it.  I would pass both variables by reference and then you can capture them by reference.  That way no copies will be made.